# SQL*Loader exit in the middle of load the data and returns 0 (No Error)

Tags: oracle, sql-loader, data-processing

Using SQL*Loader control file to load the data. The SQL*Loader(SQLLDR) is initiated from a Java class and then keeps checking the status of the SQLLDR execution. In current scenario, SQL*Loader is exited in the middle of loading the data but return code is 0 (No errors).

SQL*Loader exits in the middle of data insertion.

Consider the ELF file holds text

```
SCHEDULED DELIVERY NOTES AMANDA KYDD SPOKE TO: ANGELA SHIPPING ADDRESS: <ADDRESS DETAILS>
```

but when I check the table, the column holds a partial value only, for example:

```
SCHEDULED DELIVERY NOTES AMANDA KYDD SPOKE TO: ANG
```

Column datatype is VARCHAR2(4000), so it is not due to column length. Since the previous text values are inserted properly even though length of the text is more.

Do we need to check the configuration of SQLLDR?

When I check the log file, the number of lines SQL*Loader is referring is less than the actual lines in the ELF file.

Below is from the log file. First line for the each table says number of rows matched for the domain and third row details about not matched rows -> total number of rows - number of rows matched for the domain.

```
Table <TableName>:
  0 Rows successfully loaded.
  0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
  2423295 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
  0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.

Table <TableName1>:
  42079 Rows successfully loaded.
  0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
  2381216 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
  0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.

Table <TableName2>:
  42103 Rows successfully loaded.
  0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
  2381192 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
  0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.

Table <TableName3>:
  86280 Rows successfully loaded.
  0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
  2337015 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
  0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.

Table <TableName4>:
  0 Rows successfully loaded.
  0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
  2423295 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
  0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.
```

According to the log file, total number of lines is 2423295 but the actual number of lines in the file is 5505501.

Below is header of the log file

```
SQL*Loader: Release 12.1.0.1.0 - Production on Mon Jul 06 10:27:59 2022

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Control File:   105_1009523.ldr
Data File:      <Path>
  Bad File:     105_1009523.bad
  Discard File:  none specified
 
 (Allow all discards)

Number to load: ALL
Number to skip: 0
Errors allowed: 50
Bind array:     1000 rows, maximum of 2097152 bytes
Continuation:    none specified
Path used:      Conventional
```

Comment: Did you check SQL*Loader's **log file**? I don't know Java, but - if you posted test case (CREATE TABLE, control file, sample data), perhaps we could find something.

Comment: if I use diff ELF then the data is loaded to the tables

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what "diff ELF" is.

Comment: diff -> different.

Comment: @Littlefoot, Have checked the log file. The number of line SQL*Loader is referring is less than the actual lines in the ELF file.

SQL*Loader is referring 2423295 line but in the ELF file holds 5505501 lines. 

Have added the log file details in the issue. Please refer the same and assist me to resolve the issue.

Comment: This: `2423295 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.` says that either data is wrong (so not a single row satisfies the condition), or control file is wrong (i.e. you didn't write it correctly). Therefore, back to my first comment. Re-read it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246268/discussion-between-venkatesh-r-and-littlefoot).

Comment: @Littlefoot, Have update the log details and additional details which will give more clarity. Could you please review the issue again and assist me

Comment: Just a note on formatting posts: the `*` character marks the start of italics unless you escape it with \, which is why all your references to "SQL\*Loader" were appearing as "SQL*Loader*". Also, SO will highlight preformatted text as code and guess the language from the tags unless you add `lang-none`.